# What is the equivalent of Python's None singleton in PHP?

Tags: php, python, syntax

How do you represent the concept of "undefined" in PHP?

SQL has "`NULL`", Python has "`None`", what is the equivalent in PHP?

[updated]

Tanks everybody for the enlightening discussion ([cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao), had you
written a response rather than a comment I would choose yours).

Comment: `null`?  It's called that in just about every C-like language.

Comment: @cHao In fact it is not `null`, it is `NULL`, just as it is in C

Comment: It is either one.  I use `null` all the time.  PHP doesn't care about case there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `null`, `NULL`, `Null`, `NuLl`, etc. – are all equivalent in PHP

Comment: @knittl Fine, but it's `NULL` in C. I must say find case-sensitivity in PHP somewhat confusing.

Comment: @David: It's pretty simple, really.  Only variable names, string literals, and constants normally care about case.  Function names, type/class names, and keywords don't.  `null` is just one of those odd ducks...it happens to be a type name as well as a constant name.

Comment: Anyone know what's the deal with all the downvoting here? I seldom come to PHP questions but it looks pretty unwelcoming here!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - i got downvoted for stating its not a singleton!

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not sure that was the reason. All 4 answers and the question were down-voted. Seems vindictive to me. Anyway, I'm upvoting to offset. But I don't know what you mean by "it's not a singleton". That seems false to me and the docs you link to contradict what you say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - its a constant value, not a single reference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i don't know, but if someone did some serial downvoting the system should scan it and cancel it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php has [NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) too

Taken from the docs

> The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is
>   the only possible value of type NULL.
>
> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been unset().

Answer (score 3):

`None` in Python has its counterpart in PHP - it is `NULL` (but in PHP cases in `null` do not matter, so [`null === Null === NULL`](http://ideone.com/O67hG)).

Answer (score 1):

Its `NULL`. Its not a singleton.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: Actually, it is.  from the docs, "There is only one value of type null, and that is the case-insensitive constant NULL."  Pretty much fits the definition of a singleton, `getInstance()` aside.  :)

Comment: @cHao - null is a constant value.

Comment: It's also a type.  and the constant `null` is still the one and only possible `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [`NULL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).